# Does a good OCR of "Western Mandarin, or, The spoken language of western China" by Grainger, Adam exist?

Tags: writing

Archive.org has a really pristine scan of ["Western Mandarin, or, The spoken language of western China"](https://archive.org/details/westernmandarino00grairich) by Grainger, Adam.

It's great. It really is.

It is completely comprised of "photos", though, only. So, not really searchable, aside from a *Radical Index*, if you get your thrills in the futility of stroke order.

The "[Full Text](https://archive.org/stream/westernmandarino00grairich/westernmandarino00grairich_djvu.txt)" and "ePub" options on archive.org are awful.

E.g.:
[image: example]

and the "Full Text" version:

> ^ T and P? T
>
> servants and door keepers.

There must be a good OCR of this pdf, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, most OCR software still has trouble dealing with this type of 'non-standard' typeface.  In my experience, Chinese that is not in one of the standard computer fonts always comes out with significantly more errors than roman lettered texts. Premodern printed works come off especially badly, so unless someone has made this particularly book the subject of a major project, I doubt there is anything useful out there. Let me know if you find something!